# How to add more than 10 buttons for ChoicePrompt Bot framework V4 c#

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

I am using **ChoicePrompt** in **WaterfallStep** for displaying choices. The issue is if the choice list is greater than 10, I am not getting buttons, That's displaying as text. Please help me on how to fix this error.

```
 var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            InitializeStateStepAsync,
            PromptShowChoiceStepAsync,
            DisplaySuccessStepAsync,
        };
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog("waterfallDialog", waterfallSteps));
        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt("ShowChoicePrompt", ValidateShowChoice));

 private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ValidateShowChoice(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   return await stepContext.PromptAsync("ShowChoicePrompt", new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please select from choices"),
                RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Sorry, Please the valid choice"),
                Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(choicesList),
            }, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

If **choicesList** count is greater than 10, I am getting the buttons like this. Which is not an issue in Bot framework V3.

```
Please select from choices
1. Choice-1
2. Choice-2
3. Choice-3
4. Choice-4
5. Choice-5
6. Choice-6
7. Choice-7
8. Choice-8
9. Choice-9
10. Choice-10
11. Choice-11
12. Choice-12
13. Choice-13
```

Please help me how to resolve this error.

Comment: What channel are you using?

Comment: Facebook and skype.

Comment: Are you sure you're able to display more than 11 Facebook Quick Replies using Bot Builder v3? That seems to be a channel limitation

Comment: In Bot Builder V3 the choice prompt is displaying as buttons, so there is no issue there. Now in V4 the choice prompt is showing as quick replies.

Comment: Is Nicolas R's answer acceptable?

Comment: It's partially acceptable, It's not user-friendly to add more quick replies. But need an alternative for how to display these as buttons in prompt?

Comment: Can you explain why you're calling the choice prompt in the choice prompt's own validator function as opposed to, say, a waterfall step?

Comment: Yes, It's a waterfall step. In which I have multiple text prompts and choice prompt.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. Look at the code you've posted. You have a validator function called `ValidateShowChoice` and you're calling the prompt in that validator function, not a waterfall step.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: Yes @KyleDelaney!! It's an acceptable answer. Thank you!!

Comment: @KyleDelaney - How to display more than 10 herocards in msteams channel?

Comment: @Samadhan - You might consider sending multiple carousels with `SendActivities` instead of `SendActivity`. I suspect you'll need to ask a new question if you can find the information you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choice prompts in v3 used hero cards by default. You can force your prompts to use hero cards with the new `HeroCard` option in the [`ListStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.choices.liststyle) enum. The list style can be applied directly to the prompt when you add it to your dialog set:

```
AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt("ShowChoicePrompt", ValidateShowChoice) { Style = ListStyle.HeroCard });
```

You also now have the ability to specify a list style in the prompt options:

```
return await stepContext.PromptAsync("ShowChoicePrompt", new PromptOptions
{
    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please select from choices"),
    RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Sorry, Please the valid choice"),
    Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(choicesList),
    Style = ListStyle.HeroCard,
}, cancellationToken);
```

While it's true that it's bad practice to include too many buttons in a message and most channels enforce this convention by not allowing a lot of buttons on a card, the connectors for Facebook and Skype will automatically generate multiple cards if you try to put too many buttons on one card.

In Facebook Messenger it will look like this:

[image: Facebook Messenger]

In Skype it will look like this:

[image: Skype]

Answer (score 1):

These display choices are made due to limitations / guidelines on the channels used.

If you have a look to Facebook Messenger developer's page about `Quick replies` [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies), it states:

> Quick replies provide a way to present a set of **up to 11 buttons**
>   in-conversation that contain a title and optional image, and appear
>   prominently above the composer. You can also use quick replies to
>   request a person's location, email address, and phone number.

As a consequence, in the code of the BotBuilder available on Github, you will have a method to `Determine if a number of Suggested Actions are supported by a Channel` [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/Choices/Channel.cs#L26):

```
/// <summary>
/// Determine if a number of Suggested Actions are supported by a Channel.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="channelId">The Channel to check the if Suggested Actions are supported in.</param>
/// <param name="buttonCnt">(Optional) The number of Suggested Actions to check for the Channel.</param>
/// <returns>True if the Channel supports the buttonCnt total Suggested Actions, False if the Channel does not support that number of Suggested Actions.</returns>
public static bool SupportsSuggestedActions(string channelId, int buttonCnt = 100)
{
    switch (channelId)
    {
        // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies
        case Connector.Channels.Facebook:
        case Connector.Channels.Skype:
            return buttonCnt <= 10;

        // ...
    }
}
```

Then, in the `ChoiceFactory` that you used, the display is selected (see code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/Choices/ChoiceFactory.cs)):

```
public static IMessageActivity ForChannel(string channelId, IList<Choice> list, string text = null, string speak = null, ChoiceFactoryOptions options = null)
{
    channelId = channelId ?? string.Empty;

    list = list ?? new List<Choice>();

    // Find maximum title length
    var maxTitleLength = 0;
    foreach (var choice in list)
    {
        var l = choice.Action != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(choice.Action.Title) ? choice.Action.Title.Length : choice.Value.Length;
        if (l > maxTitleLength)
        {
            maxTitleLength = l;
        }
    }

    // Determine list style
    var supportsSuggestedActions = Channel.SupportsSuggestedActions(channelId, list.Count);
    var supportsCardActions = Channel.SupportsCardActions(channelId, list.Count);
    var maxActionTitleLength = Channel.MaxActionTitleLength(channelId);
    var hasMessageFeed = Channel.HasMessageFeed(channelId);
    var longTitles = maxTitleLength > maxActionTitleLength;

    if (!longTitles && !supportsSuggestedActions && supportsCardActions)
    {
        // SuggestedActions is the preferred approach, but for channels that don't
        // support them (e.g. Teams, Cortana) we should use a HeroCard with CardActions
        return HeroCard(list, text, speak);
    }
    else if (!longTitles && supportsSuggestedActions)
    {
        // We always prefer showing choices using suggested actions. If the titles are too long, however,
        // we'll have to show them as a text list.
        return SuggestedAction(list, text, speak);
    }
    else if (!longTitles && list.Count <= 3)
    {
        // If the titles are short and there are 3 or less choices we'll use an inline list.
        return Inline(list, text, speak, options);
    }
    else
    {
        // Show a numbered list.
        return List(list, text, speak, options);
    }
}
```

This is why you got the list if you provide more than 10 items.

Generally, it's a best practice to limit the number of buttons, more than 10 is huge. You may adapt your behaviour (grouping items / adding an additional level of selection by group for example)